# ASP.NET MVC drag and drop html 5 property don't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, drag-and-drop

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2013 with the .NET framework 4.5. I need to drag an Excel file and drop it on a `<div>` in the my web site, but this code doesn't work

```
<script>
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        alert('allowDrop');
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.id);
        alert('drag');
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        //var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
        //ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        alert('drop');
    }
</script>

<style>
    #div1, #div2 {
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        height: 35px;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    }
</style>


<script>
    $("#titulo").html("Facturas");
</script>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/img_w3slogo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

because when I try to drag the image I get the next error message

Unhandled online 55657 , column 9 in eval code
this exception occurs in this method

```
    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.id);//here occurs the exception
        alert('drag');
    }
```

I am using this code only to test the html5 drag and drop property because I need to another type of file, an Excel file, but first I need to do work the drag and drop property.

Thanks for all the help.